# funcionamiento de view binding kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Coloqué en el *gradle* el *enabled* y lo actualicé.

Tengo 2 porciones de código que me parece que cumplen la misma función, darle propiedades a ese webview.

El código comentado sería el *view binding* y lo descomentado el código tradicional, el codigo comentado no me muestra el webview o su contenido, dentro del programa.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
//val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 //binding.WV.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.ar/")
 //binding.WV.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
 //binding.WV.webViewClient = WebViewClient()


 val WV: WebView = super.findViewById(R.id.WV)
 WV.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.ar/")
 WV.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
 WV.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

Answer (score 3):

creo que lo que intentas es utilizar la biblioteca de vinculación de datos, Data Binding, tal y como dice Google esta es:

> La biblioteca de vinculación de datos es una biblioteca de compatibilidad que **permite vincular los componentes de la IU de tus diseños a las fuentes de datos de tu app** usando un formato declarativo en lugar de la programación.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding?hl=es

Dado que le estas pasando los datos directamente no necesitas utilizar esta biblioteca, otra cosa es que bien por medio de una base de datos interna o externa quieras manejar estos.

Para ello te recomiendo leas el enlace que te he puesto, no es complicada de usar, lo complicado es implementar todo lo que le rodea.

Te dejo otro enlace con un ejemplo muy sencillo que tal vez te sirva, un saludo.

https://medium.com/@jencisov/androids-data-binding-with-kotlin-df94a24ffc0f

---

Te explico el ejemplo del enlace que te he puesto...

Lo primero declarar la biblioteca:

```
android {
....
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

}

Creas la clase con los datos que vas a necesitar, en el ejemplo viene la de User, con el nombre y edad.

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

En el archivo de diseño, en este caso activity_main.xml para comenzar a usar Data Binding debes poner siempre.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
```

Este layout viene a indicar que viene código para vinculación de datos y a continuación.

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.kuma.sample.User"
        />
</data>
```

Si te fijas estas declarando en  una variable que llamamos user y que recoge todos los campos de la clase User. El código completo del layaout sería así.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
<data>

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.kuma.sample.User"
        />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.kuma.sample.MainActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@{user.name}"
        tools:text="Name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_age_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@{Integer.toString(user.age)}"
        tools:text="XX"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hemos vinculado la clase User con la vista y podemos usar las diferentes propiedades de esta como son name y age en los TextView con **android:text="@{user.name}"** y **android:text="@{Integer.toString(user.age)}"** ahora sólo queda declarar en la clase donde queremos que actúe el Data Binding.

```
package com.kuma.sample

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.kuma.kotlinsteps.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        val user = User("Kuma", 23)
        binding.setVariable(BR.user, user)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Como ves ahora si declaras el binding y se vincula con la vista para despues pasarle los datos de Kuma y 23

Espero te ayude, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que te falta la función setcontentView, primero asegúrate de haber activado el binding desde el gradle

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

En tu clase del activity declara la variable binding antes del onCreate

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

Ahora justo al iniciar el onCreate vinculalo al activity de la siguiente forma

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```